# How to get android mobile model name using mobile device id in java

Tags: java, android, servlets

I've android unique device/hardware id, I want to get android device model using device Id from Java servlet. I'll be getting this id from android SDK to Java servlet, I know we can get device model name from android SDK api itself but I've situation where we can't go and modify our sdk at this point .. so is there any way to get device model name using java api in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

How to get the android device friendly name:

```
/** Returns the consumer friendly device name */
public static String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    }
    return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
}

private static String capitalize(String str) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        return str;
    }
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    boolean capitalizeNext = true;
    String phrase = "";
    for (char c : arr) {
        if (capitalizeNext && Character.isLetter(c)) {
            phrase += Character.toUpperCase(c);
            capitalizeNext = false;
            continue;
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            capitalizeNext = true;
        }
        phrase += c;
    }
    return phrase;
}
```

Then:

```
// using method from above
System.out.println(getDeviceName());
// Using https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames
System.out.println(DeviceName.getDeviceName());
```

Comment: Thanks! Where you are passing device id in this program, I want to pass the device .. based on that id it should return device model name..

Comment: Why you don't use the Build API?

Comment: I'm not going to run this program in device...it's outside of the device..i'll be passing the android device to my REST api and I've to fetch device model name using device id